# Delete all posts with a specific custom field using meta_query

Tags: meta-query, wp-cron, date-query

I'm building a listings website using WooCommerce.

A listing is either set to `live` or `sold` inside of a custom field key `status`

Once a listing is sold then the custom field `status` is updated with `sold`.  This allows the listing to be hidden from the website, yet still able to be viewed directly, just in case users still click a link and end up on the listing page.

I am looking to automatically delete (or move to trash for now) all `sold` listings within 10 days of being sold.

When the post is updated to `sold` this also gives the `post modified` date as a point of reference for the 10 days.

I've almost got it working, after many hours of trying, and digging around online.

The cron parts are all working OK and it is almost doing what is intended...

The issue I am having is that even though I have the `meta_query` and the `date_query` set, it seems to ignore both of these and deletes ALL posts, whether the `status` custom field is `sold` or `live`, and regardless of the date specified.

Any ideas what I may be doing wrong?  Below is what I have so far.

Also tried it without the date query and just with the custom field query and it still deletes all posts, not just posts that have the custom field set to `sold`.

One things to note - some posts do not have the custom field `status` at all yet, could this be affecting it?

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
function get_delete_sold_listings() {
    // Set query arguments
    $args = array(
        'fields'         => 'ids',
        'post_type'      => 'product',
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_query'     => array(
            array(
            'key'     => 'status',
            'value'   => 'sold'
            )
        ),
        'date_query'     => array(
            array(
            'column'  => 'post_modified_gmt',
            'before'  => '10 days'
            )
        )
    );
    $q = get_posts( $args );

    // Check if any posts to delete, if not - return false
    if ( !$q )
        return false;

    // if have posts to delete - delete them
    foreach ( $q as $id )
        wp_trash_post( $id );
}

// Fires when the Cron is executed
add_action( 'sold_listing_delete', 'get_delete_sold_listings' );


// Register event to wp
add_action( 'wp', 'register_daily_listings_delete_event');

function register_daily_listings_delete_event() {
    // Make sure this event hasn't been scheduled
    if( !wp_next_scheduled( 'sold_listing_delete' ) ) {
        // Schedule the event
        wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'sold_listing_delete' );
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that the queries to do this would be _significantly_ faster and more scalable if you had used a taxonomy with terms named `live` and `sold`. I would also strongly advise against using `-1` on `posts_per_page`, you'll run into a situation where too many results are returned and the loop is never reached with no way to recover

Comment: Thank you, Tom.  Noted.  With the `live` and `sold` custom field entry - That makes sense, only I am using the WP All Import plugin which can set a custom field value if the item is no longer present in the import (and therefore sold), however there is no option to add it as a taxonomy in the same situation, unfortunately, so looks like I am stuck with a custom field for now (providing I can get the above working of course).  I will ensure to use a fixed number for the `posts_per _page` in future.  Your input is appreciated.

Comment: also, avoid using `get_posts` if you can but if you must, set `supress_filters` to false so that caching plugins etc work. This is set to true for `get_posts` for legacy reasons, `WP_Query` doesn't have this issue. I'd recommend eliminating the meta or the date to figure out which one is problematic as a debugging step

Comment: Sven, if I'm not mistaken the PRO version of WP All Import should allow you to assign imported data to a taxonomy.  It's been a while since I used it but I do believe I did get it to do that.  I can't check because the site is no longer in operation. A Pandemic casualty. :-(